# Hovercards and jQuery ..Hovercards not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I am using this plugin for hovercards..http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard

The problem with this plugin is when I hover over 'A' tags it only shows the value of the last 'A' tag and not the intended one and

E.g

```
   <a href='aaa.com'>AAA.com</a>
   <a href='bbb.com'>BBB.com</a>
   <a href= 'ccc.com>CCC.com</a>
```

Expected:
When I hover the link over AAA.com,it should show AAA.com,but it shows CCC.com

Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
       var hoverHTMLDemoOpenLeft = '<p id="aa1">' +'</p>';

  $('a').hovercard({
       detailsHTML: hoverHTMLDemoOpenLeft,
       width: 600,
       cardImgSrc: 'http://ejohn.org/files/short.sm.jpg',
       onHoverIn: function () {
       var a1=$('a').attr('href');
       alert(a1)
   }
  });
});
```

The problem here is the alert message is not showing up aaa.com when you hover over AAA.com it's showing us CCC.com And sometimes only for the first link hover is displayed but too wrongly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
onHoverIn: function () {
           var a1= $(this).find('a').attr('href');
           alert(a1);         
       }
```

Using `this` inside `onHoverIn` callback function sets scope to the (current) full hovercard div with the class of `.hc-preview`

Here's the jsFiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/VjHe8/

Answer (score 0):

You try to get the href attribute from 'global'  tag but you should use the scope object.

```
onHoverIn: function () {
       var a1=$('a').attr('href');
       alert(a1)
}
```

try to change `$('a').attr('href');` to `this.attr('href');`

Comment: You can add breakpoint (`debugger` keyword) on this place and inspect necessary variable in Firebug for example.